# Laravel Eloquent model returning empty sets with a variable in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In the code below, $request->input('id') returns an integer. I can return just that and see it every time. Or set it to a variable and return that to see it every time also. If I replace the $request->input('id') in my code with just that integer value I get what I'm looking for, however if I leave in a variable it always returns an empty set. What is going on? I'm so confused!

```
public function delete($id, Request $request)
{
    $community = Community::find($id);

    return $community->categories->where('id', $request->input('id'))->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$community->categories->where(...` you are calling the `where` method on a Collection object, which is the result of the relationship query. So, you are running both `where` and `first` with all related categories in memory, after fetching them from the database.

If you did `$community->categories()->where(...` you are calling the `where` method on a Relation object (which itself contains a Builder). In this case, the query is not triggered until you run the last method `first` (and most often `get`), and also, the `where` filtering is done by the DBMS, your application only receives the matching categories. This may be more efficient.

So, to the point of your question:

You may notice that the signature of the `Collection::where` method has a third parameter which is whether the comparison is strict, which defaults to true. My guess is the request input is coming as a string, and doesn't strictly match the id which is cast as int.

Meanwhile, the `Builder::where` method doesn't have strict comparison (again, it's not PHP who execute it). So you have no worries there.

Option 1:

```
return $community->categories->whereLoose('id', $request->input('id'))->first();
```

Option 2 (better, in my opinion):

```
return $community->categories()->where('id', $request->input('id'))->first();
```

Comment: That was an amazing answer, and thank you so much! Not only just the solution, but the full reason behind it as well. Very much appreciated!